# Swift - Convert Array to Dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I just want convert an array of Player Names into a dictionary Scoreboard, giving everyone an initial score of 0.

*Meaning...*

```
var playerNames = ["Harry", "Ron", "Hermione"]
```

*becomes*...

```
var scoreBoard: [String:Int] = [ "Ron":0, "Harry":0, "Hermione":0 ]
```

This is my first time asking a question, but I’m totally completely stuck on what feels so simple and all how-to's/questions I've found are off in some way.  I have tried using reduce in a variety of ways, but always end up short. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 44):

Here's a quick one liner that I like to use:

```
let scoreboard = playerNames.reduce(into: [String: Int]()) { $0[$1] = 0 }
```

Comment: Man, I wish I could favorite answers because this is pretty slick

Comment: Use type inference to make this even shorter… `let scoreboard = playerNames.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1] = 0 }`

Comment: What does this part mean/do? `$0[$1] = 0`

Comment: @kfkhalili, it represents first and second args of the completion block, here $0 is your partial result and $1, a player name

Answer (score 9):

`reduce` is definitely one of the more difficult builtin functions to use correctly, but it is what you want here.

```
let names = ["Harry", "Ron", "Hermione"]
let scoreboard: [String: Int] = names.reduce(into: [:], { result, next in
    result[next] = 0
})
```

It takes 2 parameters: the initial value (in our case, an empty dictionary `[:]`), and a closure that updates the result with each element in the array. This closure has 2 parameters, `result` and `next`. We want to update `result` based on the `next` element. Our closure does this by setting `result[next]` to 0.

Answer (score 8):

If the player names are known to be all different then you can do

```
let playerNames = ["Harry", "Ron", "Hermione", "Ron"]

var scoreBoard = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: zip(playerNames,
                                                      repeatElement(0, count: playerNames.count)))

print(scoreBoard) // ["Harry": 0, "Ron": 0, "Hermione": 0]
```

Here `zip` is used to create a sequence of player/score pairs, from which the dictionary is created.

*Remark:* Originally I had used `AnySequence { 0 }` to generate the zeros. Using `repeatElement()` instead was [suggested by Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58551376/1187415) and has the advantage that the correct required capacity is passed to the dictionary intializer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `reduce(into:`) as you suspected. You simply need to declare the initial value as `[String:Int]()` to be an empty `Dictionary` of the required type, then simply set the value of all keys in `playerNames` to 0.

```
var playerNames = ["Harry", "Ron", "Hermione"]
var scoreBoard = playerNames.reduce(into: [String:Int](), { currentScores,player in
    currentScores[player] = 0
})
```

Answer (score 4):

Using **[`reduce(into:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2924692-reduce)**:

```
var playerNames = ["Harry", "Ron", "Hermione"]

let playerScore = playerNames.reduce(into: [:]) { counts, playerNames in
    counts[playerNames, default: 0] += 0 
}

print(playerScore)
```

To keep a count of the players names (eg. duplicate names):

```
counts[myArray, default: 0] += 1
```

*So for example if Ron had two entries before the game started (score > 0) then you would know.*

Without using `reduce(into:_:)` method and as an extension:

```
var playerNames = ["Harry", "Ron", "Hermione"]

extension Sequence where Self.Iterator.Element: Hashable {

func freq() -> [Self.Iterator.Element: Int] {
    return reduce([:]) {
            ( iter: [Self.Iterator.Element: Int], element) in
            var dict = iter
            dict[element] = 0
            return dict
        }
    }
}

print(playerNames.freq())
// ["Harry": 0, "Hermione": 0, "Ron": 0]
```

keep a count (eg. duplicate names):

```
dict[element, default: -1 ] += 1
```

Comment: `... 0 - 1) + 1`? But why?

Comment: @Alexander: Otherwise all of the elements begin their count at `1`. I suppose `-1` could be used instead...

Comment: I don't think OP is looking to do 0-based counts of the elements. I think all entries should just have the value `0`.

Comment: `dict[element] = (dict[element] ?? 0 - 1) + 1` can be simplified to `dict[element, default: -1] += 1`. – `dict[element] = (dict[element] ?? 0)` can be simplified to `dict[element] = 0` . – But note that your approach creates several intermediate dictionaries, that is avoided with `reduce(into: ...)`

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can do that:

```
var playerNames = ["Harry", "Ron", "Hermione"]

var dictionary = [String: Int]()
for player in playerNames {
    dictionary[player] = 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it:

```swift
// Implementation 

extension Dictionary {
    static func from(_ array: [Value], key: KeyPath<Value, Key>) -> Dictionary<Key, Value> {
        var dict: Dictionary<Key, Value> = [:]
        array.forEach { dict[$0[keyPath: key]] = $0}
        return dict
    }
}


/// Usage

let array: [String] = ["Banana", "Apple"]

Dictionary.from(array, key: \.self)

// or if you have a more complex object

struct Foo {
    let id: Int
}


let array2: [Foo] = [Foo(id: 1), Foo(id: 2)]

Dictionary.from(array2, key: \.id)
```

Answer (score -2):

> Based on [jmad8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50822650/4488252) answer

### Details

- Swift 5.3
- Xcode 12.0.1 (12A7300)

### Solution

```
extension Sequence {
    func toDictionary<Key: Hashable, Value>(where closure: (Element) -> (Key, Value)) -> [Key: Value] {
        reduce(into: [Key: Value]()) { (result, element) in
            let components = closure(element)
            result[components.0] = components.1
        }
    }
    
    func toCompactDictionary<Key: Hashable, Value>(where closure: (Element) -> ((Key, Value)?)) -> [Key: Value] {
        reduce(into: [Key: Value]()) { (result, element) in
            guard let components = closure(element) else { return }
            result[components.0] = components.1
        }
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
// Sample 1

print(languages.toDictionary { (string) -> (Character, String) in
    return (string.first!, string)
})

print(languages.toCompactDictionary { (string) -> (Character, String)? in
    guard let character = string.first, character != Character("J") else { return nil }
    return (character, string)
})


// Sample 2

print(languages.enumerated().toDictionary { (data) -> (Int, String) in
    return (data.offset, data.element)
})

// Shorter version of sample 2

print(languages.enumerated().toDictionary { ($0.offset, $0.element) })

// Sample 3

struct Order {
    let id: Int
    let desctiption: String
}

let orders = [
                Order(id: 0, desctiption: "Apple"),
                Order(id: 1, desctiption: "Banana"),
                Order(id: 2, desctiption: "watermelon")
            ]

print(orders.toDictionary { ($0.id, $0) })
```