# Difference between creating a dictionary by reduce on an array vs by assigning each item on iteration

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, big-o, code-cleanup

I came across a question on StackOverflow: [Swift - Convert Array to Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50822304/swift-convert-array-to-dictionary)
where the user wants to take the elements of an array and wants to put them in a dictionary and assign 0 to each of them. (Key as Players and value as their scores)
So:

```
var playerNames = ["Harry", "Ron", "Hermione"]
```

becomes

```
var scoreBoard: [String:Int] = [ "Ron":0, "Harry":0, "Hermione":0 ]
```

This question got 2 answers:
1) Uses reduce on the array

```
let scoreboard = playerNames.reduce(into: [String: Int]()) { $0[$1] = 0 }
```

2)Creates a dictionary and iterates on array to add each value key pair to it

```
var dictionary = [String: Int]()
for player in playerNames {
    dictionary[player] = 0
}
```

I took the BenchTimer function from https://github.com/nyisztor/swift-algorithms to test both of these ways of solving. And they both seem to operate in O(n).

[image]

[image]

I was wondering why we would prefer the first one over the other since the person who wrote the second solution got a bad comment about their coding skills.

Edit: Some functionality gets deprecated by Apple in newer versions so isn't it better to stick with the basics and create our own ways to do things?

Thank you for the answers

Comment: Performance isn't everything. There isn't anything overly wrong about the 2nd piece of code either, but I see (at least) 1 downside compared to the first solution using `reduce`, namely: `dictionary` has to be `immutable` for the solution to work. The `for` is more lines of code as well, but whether that is considered more readable or not is subjective.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I think you mean the dictionary has to be `mutable` for it to work in the second case. You can now edit it and make me look daft :-)

Comment: @flanker you're right, I meant `mutable` :) Can't edit the comment anymore, since its been 5+ mins :)

Comment: That question had 6 answers. How does MartinR’s answer perform compared to those 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today, IMO, you shouldn't use either of these. We now have `Dictionary.init(uniqueKeysWithValues:)` and `.init(_:uniquingKeysWith:)` which much more clearly state their intent, and make corner cases, such as duplicate keys, explicit.

If you statically can prove that all the keys are unique, then you would use the first one:

```
let scoreboard = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: playerNames.map { (name: $0, score: 0) })
```

If you cannot prove the keys are unique, you'd use the second one, which would allow you to explicitly decide what to do in cases of conflict.

```
let scoreboard = Dictionary(playerNames.map { (name: $0, score: 0) },
                            uniquingKeysWith: { first, _ in first })
```

Note how this approach allows labels to make clear what the key is and what the value is. I haven't benchmarked this code, but I would expect it to be very similar in terms of time to the others.

Comment: Thanks! This is why I was confused when many people voted the reduce way up. Using something for a reason it is not made to be used could fail when they change the way it works.

Comment: @tiw `reduce` won't be going anywhere. It has very clearly defined semantics, that are no more likely to change than `Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues:)`.

Answer (score 2):

> so isn't it better to stick with the basics and create our own ways to do things?

I don't think so. The Swift community certainly isn't of that mindset. Swift prioritizes making meaningful abstractions and simplifications, so-long as they're valuable, progressively disclosable.

The Go community shares your line of thinking, but it's quite painful (IMO). The Go standard library doesn't even have an API for reversing a String. You have to cook it yourself. And it's harder than most people think. If you think it's a simple matter of making a loop to reverse the bytes, nope, that's totally broken for unicode (but would likely go unnoticed with simple ASCII test cases like `"hello"` or whatever).

Similarly, if you write `for` loops every time you want to implement `map`, you might forget to call `Array.reserveCapacity(_:)`. Forgetting that will cause multiple array allocations, and make your `O(n)`-looking algorithm into actually being (amortized) `O(n^2)`. There's lets of little performance or correctness "gotchas" like this, so there's a great benefit to using popular, shared implementations of these things.

We stand on the shoulders of giants. We couldn't do that if we were all preoccupied with reinventing wheels.

### About the two pieces of code

I wouldn't use either of them

The first approach:

1. Uses a function (`reduce`), but not the right one for the job (`Dictionary.init(uniqueKeysWithValues:)`). See [https://github.com/amomchilov/Blog/blob/master/Don't%20abuse%20reduce.md](https://github.com/amomchilov/Blog/blob/master/Don%27t%20abuse%20reduce.md)
2. Forgets to reserve capacity on the dictionary, so it causes multiple resizing operations (which involve memory reallocation, and rehashing of all keys in the dictionary)

The second approach:

1. Leaves the dictionary unecessarily mutable
2. Also forgets to reserve capacity.

Instead, I would recommend [Rob Napier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58549582/3141234) or [Martin R's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50822515/3141234). Both of them are more expressive of your intent. Rob's also uses a sequence with a known size, which allows `Dictionary.init(uniqueKeysWithValues:)` to internally allocate enough memory  up-front for the dictionary as will be necessary to fit all values.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. You meant: first approach abuses reduce and the second leaves dictionary mutable.

Comment: *“which internally allocates enough memory up-front for the dictionary”* – I am afraid that this does not apply to my uniqueKeysWithValues+zip approach, because zip returns a sequence whose length is not known a priori. On the other hand, it avoids the creation of an intermediate array. Depending on the number of elements, this may or may not be relevant.

Comment: @tiw Ah, yes, I got them mixed up. Fixed.

Comment: @MartinR Actually, `Zip2Sequence` has a known `underestimatedCount`, equal to the min of the 2 member sequences. But `AnySequence` prob has an underestimated count of 0. https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Zip.swift#L148-L154 I guess using `zip(keys, repeating(0, count: array.count)` or `keys.lazy.map { (key: $0, value: 0) }` would be better

Comment: @Alexander: Good to know! I think it was different when I checked last time, but I may be wrong. So `repeating(0, count: array.count)` should be better than `AnyIterator { 0 }` (and it avoids calling a closure on each iteration).

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you should prefer the functional idiom (ie reduce) over the for loop, for a couple of reasons:

1. The functional version conveys intent. In this case we are
   reducing an array into a dictionary -- not the best example, but
   usually reduce transforms a vector into a single scalar through some
   combining function.
2. The functional version is correct by default since its been tested.  This may seem trivial in the case of reduce, but its much less so if you look at something like `shuffled`.  How easily can you look at a for loop and tell me if its performing a Fisher Yates shuffle and if that shuffle is implemented correctly?  Similarly a pipeline of functions is much easier to read than a bunch of sequential for loops or a single for loop that does 5 different things.
3. The functional version is often (but not in this case) immutable and immutable values are easier to reason about than mutable state, because they never change.
4. The functional methods on `Swift.Sequence` mostly have analogous methods on `Combine.Publisher`.  That means you can use a single set of functional idioms across all sequences, whether or not they are synchronous or asynchronous/reactive.

Comment: I think `reduce` gets abused far too often, specifically *because* it doesn't convey intent. It's much more powerful than `map`, `filter`, etc., which comes with the downside of being less expressive (since it could possibly do so many things)

Comment: I don't really agree with your first point. `reduce` produces a single output, but that output is often a `Collection` (so a vector, not a scalar). I'd say the main difference between `map` and `reduce` is the fact that `reduce` doesn't do a 1-1 mapping between the elements of the input collection and the elements of the output collection even if its return value is a collection. Using `reduce` to create a `Dictionary` as an output is quite common, but you could also easily return an `Array` or any other collection types too.